# How to get word from CurrentInputConnection in android?

Tags: android

I am working on custom InputConnection in android. Everything is working fine, but i want to get characters between cursor's current position and start position of particular word.

Is there any suggestion? how can i do that?

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getSelectionStart() might be the answer here. It return the position of the cursor. Then parse the text from 0 to that position. This comes from TextView.

If u want to get that information from InputConnection, it's hard because there is no API for getting the cursor position there.